# Is it possible to include libs in a project using chaquopy without any server (only local files)?

Tags: android, python, integration, libraries, chaquopy

I am working on a project using **Chaquopy**, using codes in python to proceed with some complex analyses. I intend to import python libraries without to use any server (only local files).

I followed [this documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html), but the bellow error appears during the build.

> Error:
>   Cause: buildPython failed (org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'py'' finished with non-zero exit value 1).

Does anybody know where to put the binaries to install the libs directly from the project, without any online repository?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the whole error message. You might need to click the "ab" button in the Build window to show it.